# Calculate time difference from this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:

```
select  A_In.emp_reader_id as empId,A_In.Belongs_to,B.emp_name,A_In.DeviceSerialNumber,
        DT as EntryTime,
        (
         select min(DT) as OutTime
         from   trnevents A_Out
         where  EVENTID like '0'
         and    A_Out.emp_reader_id = A_In.emp_reader_id
         and    A_Out.DT > A_In.DT and DATEDIFF(day,A_In.Dt,A_Out.DT)=0
        ) as ExitTime


from    trnevents A_In
```

i need to get calculate difference from entrytime and exittime.
I used

> DATEDIFF(HOUR,A_In.DT,A_out.ExitTime)

Shows error :The multi-part identifier "A_out.exittime" could not be bound.

Anyone help ..

Comment: cross apply your min outtime to your rows.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desire results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cross apply to apply your mindate to your rows, and then take the difference.

Read more about apply [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Select A_In.emp_reader_id as empId,A_In.Belongs_to,B.emp_name,A_In.DeviceSerialNumber,
            DT as EntryTime,x.OutTime, Datediff(HOUR,a_in.DT,x.Outtime) as DifferenceTime from trnevents a_in
    CROSS APPLY (select min(DT) as OutTime
             from   trnevents A_Out
             where  EVENTID like '0'
             and    A_Out.emp_reader_id = A_In.emp_reader_id
             and    A_Out.DT > A_In.DT and DATEDIFF(day,A_In.Dt,A_Out.DT)=0
    ) x
```

Answer (score 1):

You have basically three choices:  a subquery, CTE, or `apply`.  The latter looks like:

```
select  A_In.emp_reader_id as empId, A_In.Belongs_to, B.emp_name, A_In.DeviceSerialNumber,
        A_In.DT as EntryTime, A_Out.ExitTime,
        datediff(hour, A_In.DT, A_out.ExitTime) as hourdiff
from trnevents A_In outer apply
     (select min(DT) as ExitTime
      from trnevents
      where EVENTID = 0 and
            A_Out.emp_reader_id = A_In.emp_reader_id
            A_Out.DT > A_In.DT and DATEDIFF(day, A_In.Dt, A_Out.DT) = 0
     ) A_Out;
```

Notes:

- This is can probably be more efficiently written using window functions.
- `EVENTID` is probably a number.  In any case, I recommend `=` rather than `LIKE` if you don't have wildcards.
- `DATEDIFF()` counts the number of hour "transitions" between two values.  So, 1:59:59 and 2:00:01 are one hour apart.  Often, you want to take the difference in seconds and divide by (60*60).
- `B.emp_name` is not defined.  I assume this is a mistranscription of your original query.

Comment: Nice spotted with b.Emp_name

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but why not just cross apply? Isnt it faster. Outer apply and cross apply will give the same here? or am i wrong?

Comment: @plaidDK . . . `cross apply` is not equivalent to the original query.  It will filter out rows that have no corresponding "out" record.

Comment: But it only selects a min row? There is no where or join condition after the apply so would it even matter?

Comment: @plaidDK . . . That's true.  The value will be `NULL` in this case.  Still seems dangerous, though.

Comment: Some Null handling might be needed, but thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a Column `A_out.exittime` names in your Query.

But I assume Using `OUTER APPLY` may fix your problem.

```
SELECT A_In.emp_reader_id AS empId,
       A_In.Belongs_to,
       B.emp_name,
       A_In.DeviceSerialNumber,
       DT AS EntryTime,
      ExitTime = E.OutTime
FROM trnevents A_In
    OUTER APPLY
    (
          SELECT MIN(DT) AS OutTime
          FROM trnevents A_Out
          WHERE EVENTID LIKE '0'
               AND A_Out.emp_reader_id = A_In.emp_reader_id
               AND A_Out.DT > A_In.DT
               AND DATEDIFF(day, A_In.Dt, A_Out.DT) = 0
    )E;
```